# The number of limit cycles of a quadratic vector field with a unique singularity

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, limit-cycles

Is there  a  uniform upper  bound for  the  number of  limit  cycles  of  a  quadratic  vector  field  which  has a  unique  singular point in the plane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This survey](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Limit_cycles_of_planar_polynomial_vector_fields#Quadratic_Systems) seems to indicate that the answer is $1.$

Comment: Thank  you  for this  survey.  What  part of  the  survey indicate to $1$? Does the  class  I contains  all quadratic  vector  field  with a  unique  singularity?